Row-level security with session_context doesn't work after refreshing token
I have a multi-tenant database, I use Row-level security to filter/block data for every table. Every time someone queries the table, they need to set up the session context. I have a API set up where users can log in and run get/post data. Once a user logs in, I add the user id in a static class. I use this when setting up the session (see below).
I also implemented JWT and refresh tokens. Every API request is protected.
The issue is, when a user sends a request to the API the first time using the JWT token, they get the correct response. The RLS works as it should. It only returns the rows for this user. But when the user refreshes the token and they use the updated token, the results are returned as 200 but it's empty.
I assume the issue is with the session context, because the JWT token was authorized to send the request. It's the RLS that returns an empty table.
Code to set up the session in .NET:
using (SqlCommand command =new SqlCommand("EXEC sp_set_session_context @key=N'UserId', @value=@UserId", conn))
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", LoggedInUser.UserId);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

Refresh token code:
public async Task<AuthResult> RefreshTokenAsync(string refreshtoken)
{
    var refreshToken = await context.RefreshTokens.FirstOrDefaultAsync(r => r.Token == refreshtoken);
    //Some checks on the validation of the refresh token like if it's expired etc.
    var getUser = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(refreshToken.UserId);
    var getUserRole = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(getUser);
    var userSession = new UserSession(getUser.Id, getUser.Name, getUser.Email, getUserRole.First());
    context.RefreshTokens.Remove(refreshToken);
    return await GenerateJwtTokenAsync(userSession, deviceid);
}

public async Task<AuthResult> GenerateJwtTokenAsync(UserSession user)
{
    var claims = new[]
    {
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.Name),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role,user.Role)
    };

    var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(config["Jwt:Key"]!));
    var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
        issuer: config["Jwt:Issuer"],
        audience: config["Jwt:Audience"],
        claims: claims,
        expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5),
        signingCredentials: creds);

    var jwtToken = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);

    var refreshToken = new RefreshToken
    {
        Token = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        JwtId = token.Id,
        IsRevoked = false,
        UserId = user.Id,
        AddedDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
        ExpiryDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(1)
    };

    await context.RefreshTokens.AddAsync(refreshToken);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return new AuthResult
    {
        Token = jwtToken,
        RefreshToken = refreshToken.Token,
        Success = true
    };
}

Code to login which is the only place I set the user id:
private async Task<AuthResult> LoginAccountAsync(Login login)
{
    var getUser = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(login.Email);

    var getUserRole = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(getUser);
    var userSession = new UserSession(getUser.Id, getUser.Name, getUser.Email, getUserRole.First());
    ApplicationUser getUser = response.User;

    bool checkUserPassword = await userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(getUser, login.Password);
    //Some checks...
    LoggedInUser.UserId = getUser.Id; //Setting the LoggedInUser static class.
    return await GenerateJwtTokenAsync(userSession);
}

I tried to debug it by returning the session context from the database after I ran the other query, and it returned the correct session. I ran the query in SQL setting up the same session context, and it returned the correct results. Also, this works as it should before the refresh token is called.
Can anyone spot an issue? How would I debug this issue? Is there a way for me to debug it in the database to see all the queries that were executed?
I encountered this issue using a published Azure (testing) database. I tested it using a local database, and there doesn't seem to be any issue.
Edit
The full code that runs when querying the database:
private static DataTable DoExecuteSQL(SqlCommand cmd, bool loadtable)
{
    DataTable dt = new();

    using (SqlConnection conn = new(ConnectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        if (LoggedInUser.UserId != null)
        {
            using (SqlCommand command =new SqlCommand("EXEC sp_set_session_context @key=N'UserId', @value=@UserId", conn))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", LoggedInUser.UserId);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        try
        {
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (loadtable)
            {
                dt.Load(dr);
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            string msg = ParseConstraintMsg(ex.Message);
            throw new Exception(msg);
        }
        catch (InvalidCastException ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(cmd.CommandText + ": " + ex.Message, ex);
        }
    }

    return dt;
}

Then I'm converting it to a object which gets returned to the API.

how does the RLS code look? If you lose the session context between calls (it's a connection setting), maybe it's not so strange it doesn't work? I think connection pooling or whatever reset the session context

@siggemannen See my edit. Another thing to note is that I tested it by querying the DB to return the current session context after calling the other code (it was not at the same time that it returned empty results), and it returned the session context.

RLS, maybe we're talking about different things, but isn't there supposed to be some sql policy and a function checking stuff?

Yes I have a security policy quite similar to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security?view=sql-server-ver16#MidTier. It works in SQL, it works in the API as it should for the first time (and sometimes more than once). The issue only happens after I refresh the token after a long time not calling the API.
